# Induced representation in Etingoff. Remark 5.8.2

Tags: representation-theory

In Etingoff’s notes on representation theory, he states in remark 5.8.2 that $Hom_H(k[G],V)$ is naturally isomorphic to $Ind_H^G(V)$ as representations. But I can’t quite see how this is so. $Ind_H^G(V)$ is a representation of $G$ but how is $Hom_H(k[G],V)$ also a representation of $G$? Or is the isomorphism of representations with respect to the subgroup $H$? Or is it just a simple isomorphism of vector spaces? Could someone care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an isomorphism of representations. The $G$-action is a little bit buried: when we consider $\text{Hom}_H(k[G], V)$ the natural $H$-action on $k[G]$ is by left multiplication. $k[G]$ has both a left and right $k[G]$-module structure given by left and right multiplication respectively, so there's a right $G$-action on $k[G]$ that is left "untouched" and, by contravariance, gives a *left* $G$-action on $\text{Hom}_H(k[G], V)$.

I feel duty-bound to point out also that this isomorphism only holds if $H$ has finite index in $G$ (probably in context $G$ and $H$ are even finite). Otherwise there are two induced representations (given by the left and right adjoint of restriction) and this is one of them (the right adjoint); the other one (the left adjoint) is the tensor product $k[G] \otimes_H V$ (with the $G$-action given by left multiplication this time) and they have different dimensions in general.

Comment: Thanks but Just to clarify, we can define the representation as follows: $g\cdot \phi(f)=\phi(fg)$. But I don’t see why the isomorphism should require the index to be finite.

Comment: @Jhon: yes, that's right. Take $G$ to be an infinite group, take $H = 1$, and take $V = k$. Then the right adjoint is a product of $|G|$ copies of $k$ (as a representation it's $k^G$) and the left adjoint is a direct sum of $|G|$ copies of $k$ (as a representation it's $k[G]$); these have different dimensions if $G$ is infinite (e.g. if $G$ is countable the latter has countable dimension but the former has uncountable dimension).

Comment: Thanks. But I defined the isomorphism $\psi:Hom_H(K[G],V)\rightarrow Ind_H^G(V)$ as follows $\psi(\phi)=\phi\circ i $ where $i$ is the inclusion of $G$ into $k[G]$. This isomorphism after checking was a representation isomorphism. But I can’t see the use of the finiteness requirement in this definition. Is is implicit within the definition?

Comment: @Jhon: like I said, there are two different definitions of induction, and they only agree if $H$ has finite index in $G$. If this is the one you're using then that's fine but it's also common to use the other one which is $k[G] \otimes_H V$ and these don't agree if $H$ has infinite index in $G$.